# Handle DragDrop from MS Teams C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, microsoft-teams

Trying to accept a dropped image from a MS Teams chat into a WinForms application, currently there are the following 13 formats available

[image]

I was first trying to read the content as HTML and get the image URL which returns a value like this

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000136
EndHTML:0000001213
StartFragment:0000000172
EndFragment:0000001177
SourceURL:about:blank#blocked
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><img class="ui-image al gg yz bki ahs do gk bku bkv bkw bkx bky bkz 
bla blb blc bld ble blf blg bkj bkk chb ui-animation bkg bkh xv agv ack ui-known-width-   
and-height" 
data-tid="lazy-image-2" 
alt="image" 
id="x_0-sau-d3-{randomGuid}" 
itemtype="http://schema.skype.com/AMSImage" 
data-inline-image-type="none" 
src="blob:https://teams.microsoft.com/{random-guid}" 
aria-label="image" data-track="true" 
data-track-action-gesture="click" 
data-track-action-outcome="inspect" 
data-track-action-scenario-type="readMsgs" 
data-track-action-scenario="messageOpenImage" 
data-track-module-name="imageLightbox" 
data-track-module-type="message" 
data-orig-src="https://au-prod.asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com/v1/objects/0-sau-d3-{randomguid}/views/imgo" 
data-gallery-id="gallery-1658361592997-1658361592997-https://au-prod.asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com/v1/objects/0-sau-d3-{randomguid}/views/imgpsh_fullsize" 
data-is-focusable="true" 
tabindex="0"><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to download the contents of any of the URI's I get a 401 Unauthorised error.

I then tried to get the contents of `DragImageBits` and load it from `Image.FromStream(ms)` but that gave a paramater out of value exception.

Is there a better way of downloading the blob but using some form of HTTP Authorisation to workaround the 401 error? It works fine when dragging the image out from MS Teams into MS Explorer so its obviously possible.

Comment: Are you developing Microsoft teams App?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT No - just want to accept drops from MS Teams app